# Proper permissions for python installation directory?

Tags: python, permissions, installation

I'm trying to use a python app on a server for the first time.  I started by adding setuptools as root:

`[root@server mydirectory]# yum install python-setuptools`

Cool. Then I try setup.py:

```
[user@server mydirectory]$ python setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/test-easy-install-25752.write-test'
```

This directory `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages` is owned by root, so that makes sense.

My question is, should I chmod the site-packages directory, or should I be running setup.py as root?

Comment: Can you move to a virtualenv? does your server support virtualenv?

Comment: good question - haven't tried on this server.  I'll look into it.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: See other answers (e.g. @abarnert 's one) for more details. Have no more clues than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to install stuff system-wide as a non-root user is to use `sudo`. Which is why you see things like this all over the Python docs:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Some people prefer to instead make the site-packages group-writable by some "dev" group so you don't need to do this. (This is effectively what the Mac package manager Homebrew does.)

---

Alternatively, you can install into per-user site packages. Not every project can do this, but anything based on modern `setuptools` should be able to do so.

And, while we're at it, if you're installing stuff based on modern `setuptools`, it's probably better to `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install` anyway. That will, among other benefits, create egg-info files so the package can be detected as a dependency, uninstalled, etc.

See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) for more information.

---

Finally, you may want to consider using a [virtual environment](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#venv-def). With Python 3.3+, this is built in as [`venv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), although it doesn't have its own `pip` until 3.4. With earlier versions of Python, you can install [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) off PyPI.

Many hosted server environments for Python (2.x or 3.x) come with `virtualenv` pre-installed. If not, installing *it* system-wide will of course require you to be root… but after that, you will be able to install (most) other packages into per-project virtual environments instead of system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

Installing packages with pip/easy_install and running directly setup.py files require root privileges because they read/write in those restricted folders.

Usually hosts like www.openshift.com support a virtualenv for you so you just activate it and you have your own per-user environment. Affecting the global site-packages is usually forbidden since it may be a shared host.

In my experience, in a local ubuntu-installed laptop, I have two options:

1. Run installs as sudo
2. Run installs in a virtualenv

perhaps your host, if shared, supports virtualenv. Try asking them if it doesn't support it.