# Syntax error with pip install

Tags: python-2.7, installation, syntax-error, pip, rhel5

I am on an RHEL5 machine, and I installed pip by running the get-pip.py file as suggested on the pip website. Upon trying to install a couple different modules using pip, I ran into an error traceback identical to the first one in this post: [Error installing python packages on Fedora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859089/error-installing-python-packages-on-fedora)

However, THERE IS NO ISSUE WITH MY PYTHON VERSION. I am running 2.7.6. The supposedly successfully installed pip version is 1.5.6. Has anybody seen this problem before? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: RHEL5 is super old, and probably has Python 2.4 installed (in addition to 2.7.6, which I'm assuming you installed yourself). Is it possible that pip is using 2.4?

Comment: Yes, RHEL has 2.4 installed as well. I suspected that was the problem, but I am not sure how to tell pip to look at 2.7 instead.

Comment: What command did you use to run `get-pip.py`?

Comment: `sudo python get-pip.py`, and I made sure that the python that is used when making calls from the terminal is 2.7.

Comment: if you open up the pip script itself (`vim \`which pip\``), what python executable is it using (`#!/usr/bin/<something here>`)?

Comment: The wrong one! I fixed it, but now there is a new error whenever I run pip with a traceback that ends in `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6`. I can't show the full traceback for contractual reasons, but I hope that is enough.

Comment: Hmm, if you re-run the pip installation with `python2.7 get-pip.py`, does that fix things?

Comment: That just results in `Requirement already up-to-date`...`python2.7/site-packages`. Pip is already associated with 2.7, but something else is somehow going wrong.